# Sharing a Redis database?

Tags: redis, redistogo

I'm using Redis as a session store in my app. Can I use the same instance (and db) of Redis for my job queue? If it's of any significance, it's hosted with redistogo.

Comment: you can use a redis list as a job queue.
http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine to use the same redis for multiple operations.
We had a similar use case where we used Redis as a key value store as well as a job queue. 
However you may want to consider other aspects like the performance requirements for your application. Redis can ideally handle around 70k operations per second and if at some time in future you think you may hit these benchmarks it's much better to split your operations to multiple redis instances based on the kind of operations you perform. This will allow you to make decisions about availability and replication at a more finer level depending on the requirements. As a simple use case once your key size grows you may be able to flush your session app redis or shard your keys using redis cluster without affecting job queing infrastructure.